# How to use Modbus TCP Connection Observer

Tags: c++, qt, modbus

I'm working on a Modbus server using QT libraries.
Currently I want to get better control over the server and I'm looking for a correct way to implement ConnectionObserver in my code.

installConnectionObserver function from QT documentation need a (QModbusTcpConnectionObserver *observer) as a argument, but QModbusTcpConenctionObserver is a virtual class so i can't create object of this class.

Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: why you do not implement "acceptNewConnection" function and always return true?

Comment: Have you derived QModbusTcpConnectionObserver and implemented the pure virtual functions?